# Reading active socket successively in sml

Tags: sockets, sml, smlnj

I am trying to send a message to a server so that the client(I) can interactively communicate with host.I would want the messages(responses) from host to be returned but here I am only getting the first response instead.
Here is the main function which is supposed do the job,it should return a string list of responses from host.May you help me figure out where I am making the error...

```
fun readServer (host, port, msgs) = 
  let
    val oop = openServer (host, port);
    val mystream =
      List.tabulate (length msgs, fn i =>
        (socketSend (oop, (List.nth (msgs, i))), (socketReceive (oop, 100000))))
  in
    map #2 mystream
  end;
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the socket API you are using, maybe you can provide its documentation or the types of the functions `openServer`, `socketSend`, `socketReceive`?

Comment: `fun socketSend (sock, msg) = 
    Socket.sendVec(
 sock, 
 Word8VectorSlice.full(Byte.stringToBytes(msg)) 
    );`
                                                                                                                                      
`fun socketReceive (sock, maxbytes) = 
    Byte.bytesToString(
 Socket.recvVec(sock, maxbytes)
    );`                                                                   I finally figured out how,these functions helped me create the sockect i needed